# SQL - choose column if the sum of other columns is above total

Tags: sql, select, sum

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id , name , price , date

1    a      100      1.3.12
2    b      230      1.3.12
3    a      300      1.3.12
4    c      1000     1.3.12
5    b      160      1.3.12
6    a      400      1.3.12
```

I want to display the names whose total price is above some value, let's say 500.
So if `a` has 100, 300, 400 then its total is 800 > 500 -> display.

But I want to do it with just one query. So far, I managed to get this query:

```
SELECT name SUM (price) AS total FROM table GROUP BY name
```

But then I need to do one more in order to select total > 500.

How do I do it? thank you in advance.

Comment: lol yes, but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HAVING clause to apply a condition to an aggregated function:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     yourtable
GROUP BY name
HAVING   SUM(price)>500
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `having` to filter

```
select name, sum(price) as total_price
from your_table
group by name
having total_price > 500
```

Comment: This is not standard and most likely not widely supported. (MySQL is the only product of this kind that comes to mind.)

Comment: Sorry, just realised that my comment might appear vague (if not to you then to someone else). The non-standard thing I was talking about was your referencing the `total_price` alias in the `having` clause.